# Changing cursor in codebehind and/or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cursor

How can I change the cursor to a "wait" and then back to default in the codebehind using jQuery?

The first 2 lines of the code work fine on their own (if I remove the rest of the code). If I add the rest of the code only the `//here I call stored procedure, pass parameters to a class function, which writes excel file and sends it with httpresponse` works - the JavaScript function doesn't get called.

```
protected void PACR_btnclick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)        
{
    string myScript = "cursorWait();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RegisterStartupScript", myScript, true);

        //here I call stored procedure, pass parameters to a class function, which writes excel file and sends it with httpresponse

    string myScript = "cursorDefault();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RegisterStartupScript", myScript, true);
}
```

javascript:

```
function cursorWait() {
    $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
    alert("progress");
 }
 function cursorDefault() {
     alert("default");
    $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: I assume this is a long-running task feature?  If so, this won't quite work the way you expect; because the server will process completely before the client even renders.

Comment: Yes I'm using asp.net.

Comment: @BrianMains, yes the task takes long time, that's why I want to change cursor to hourglass and then change it back. But don't know how I can do that. Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this? It doesn't have to be javascript.

Comment: There isn't a way to use an ASP.NET page to do this, but you could use a web service or pagemethods approach instead.

Comment: @BrianMains, thank you, could you point me in the right direction, maybe some useful articles,links on web service/pagemethods aproaches.

Comment: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ or http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/08/28/creating-and-consuming-aspnet-ajax-page-methods.aspx